# Is it guaranteed that the goroutine which is pending on the channel first will eventually get the data first?

Tags: go

In the code below, does Go runtime guarantee that the goroutine I started at line 16 will always get the data first and the goroutine I started at line 20 will never have a chance to get the data? Or is it unpredictable? See the code: [snippet: go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/EBRB4ch7t_t)

```
package main

import (
    "time"
    "fmt"
)

func g(c chan int) {
    v, ok := <-c
    fmt.Println(">>>", v, ok)
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan int)
    
    // Line 16
    go g(c)
    
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    
    // Line 20
    go g(c)
    
    c <- 233
    close(c)
    
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
}
```

Comment: No it doesn't. Goroutine scheduling is not deterministic. You need explicit synchronization for deterministic order.

Comment: Unpredictable. There simply is no "first" (technically "happens before" HB) unless you use some synchronisation primitives. The fact that you have two goroutines and one is "older" doesn't mean anything.

Comment: There is no guarantee, and moreover, if it matters which channel consumer gets a particular value from a channel, you're using channels incorrectly and need to rethink your design.

Answer (score 0):

If you want messages to preserve order, one of the options is creating channel for each goroutine. Little example:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    channels := make([]chan int, 4)
    for i := range channels {
        channels[i] = make(chan int)
        go func(i int) {
            channels[i] <- (<-channels[i] * 2) // parentheses are just for readability
        }(i)
    }

    for i, ch := range channels {
        ch <- i
    }

    for _, ch := range channels {
        fmt.Println(<-ch)
    }
}
```

This reliably outputs:

```
0
2
4
6
```